# How to scale 30 seconds to data to 60 minute data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a heatmap for the entire day. I'm not sure how to utilise the 'scale time()' function with the time being measured in 30-second increments. I would like to have on x axis hourly distribution.

[image]

```
Sample code:

library(ggplot2)


df<-as.data.frame(df)

df<-na.omit(df)
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time)


df$WeekDay<-factor(df$WeekDay,levels = c("Friday", "Thursday"))



p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=WeekDay) )+ 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Temperature))+
  scale_x_time(breaks = hms::hms(hours = seq(0, 24, 2))) + # not sure if this line is correct
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0, 0))+
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::hms(c("08:00:00", "18:00:00")),col = "blue", lwd = 2, lty=2)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x="", y ="", fill="Temperature", title="Temperature/Day")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=14), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="right",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(4, "cm")
  )

p
```

[image] # I would like to remove the bar charts

Sample data

```
 df<-structure(list(Date = c("1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023", 
    "1/26/2023", "1/26/2023"), Time = structure(c(37359, 33975, 34005, 
    34035, 34065, 34095, 34125, 34155, 34185, 34215, 34245, 34275, 
    34305, 34335, 34365, 34395, 34425, 34455, 34485, 34515, 34545, 
    34575, 34605, 34635, 34665, 34695, 34725, 34755, 34785, 34815, 
    34845, 34875, 34905, 34935, 34965, 34995, 35025, 35055, 35085, 
    35115, 35145, 35175, 35205, 35235, 35265, 35295, 35325, 35355, 
    35385, 35415, 35445, 35475, 35505, 35535, 35565, 35595, 35625, 
    35655, 35685, 35715, 35745, 35775, 35805, 35835, 35865, 35895, 
    35925, 35955, 35985, 36015, 36045, 36075, 36105, 36135, 36165, 
    36195, 36225, 36255, 36285, 36315, 36345, 36375, 36405, 36435, 
    36465, 36495, 36525, 36555, 36585, 36615, 36645, 36675, 36705, 
    36735, 36765, 36795, 36825, 36855, 36885, 36915), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs"), Humidity = c(43.5, 43.4, 42.8, 
    42.5, 42.8, 42.7, 42.6, 42.3, 42.4, 42.6, 42.2, 42, 41.9, 41.9, 
    41.9, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.9, 42, 42.1, 42, 42.1, 42.2, 42.6, 
    42.3, 42.1, 42.4, 42.6, 42.9, 42.9, 42.8, 42.7, 42.8, 42.8, 42.9, 
    43.2, 43.6, 43.5, 43.5, 43.6, 43.7, 43.7, 43.8, 43.9, 44, 44, 
    44.1, 44.1, 44.2, 44.2, 44.3, 44.3, 44.3, 44.2, 44.5, 44.3, 44.3, 
    44.3, 44.4, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.7, 44.7, 44.7, 44.7, 
    44.7, 44.6, 44.6, 44.6, 44.6, 44.7, 44.9, 44.8, 44.8, 44.8, 44.8, 
    44.8, 44.8, 44.8, 44.8, 44.7, 44.5, 44.4, 44.3, 44.4, 44.4, 44.5, 
    44.7, 44.8, 44.8, 44.9, 45, 45, 45.1, 45.2, 45.3), Temperature = c(23.56, 
    23.44, 23.44, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.56, 23.61, 23.67, 23.67, 
    23.67, 23.61, 23.61, 23.61, 23.61, 23.56, 23.56, 23.5, 23.5, 
    23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.44, 23.44, 23.44, 23.44, 23.44, 23.39, 
    23.39, 23.39, 23.33, 23.33, 23.28, 23.28, 23.22, 23.22, 23.22, 
    23.22, 23.17, 23.17, 23.17, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.06, 
    23.06, 23.06, 23.06, 23.06, 23, 23, 23, 22.94, 22.94, 22.94, 
    22.89, 22.89, 22.89, 22.83, 22.83, 22.83, 22.83, 22.78, 22.78, 
    22.78, 22.78, 22.78, 22.78, 22.72, 22.72, 22.72, 22.72, 22.72, 
    22.72, 22.72, 22.72, 22.72, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 
    22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.67, 22.61, 22.61, 
    22.61, 22.56, 22.56, 22.56, 22.56, 22.56), CO2 = c(1810, 1588, 
    1549, 1561, 1595, 1583, 1595, 1595, 1593, 1658, 1656, 1624, 1598, 
    1575, 1562, 1552, 1543, 1536, 1532, 1543, 1553, 1558, 1565, 1581, 
    1617, 1656, 1611, 1596, 1616, 1657, 1686, 1681, 1657, 1635, 1633, 
    1632, 1644, 1714, 1724, 1712, 1706, 1708, 1714, 1727, 1741, 1753, 
    1764, 1776, 1784, 1787, 1782, 1783, 1782, 1784, 1784, 1770, 1756, 
    1753, 1751, 1749, 1757, 1764, 1749, 1733, 1753, 1772, 1774, 1781, 
    1795, 1799, 1792, 1779, 1775, 1760, 1768, 1781, 1783, 1790, 1791, 
    1791, 1782, 1791, 1804, 1807, 1810, 1802, 1788, 1787, 1794, 1791, 
    1796, 1795, 1793, 1785, 1782, 1807, 1818, 1806, 1819, 1847), 
        WeekDay = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L), .Label = c("Friday", "Thursday"), class = "factor"), 
        Month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January")), row.names = c(NA, 
    100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data only has data for `Thursday` and only between about 9:20 and 10:20. So some of the features you want do not apply - e.g. `geom_vline` - at least not where you want them to be. I have therefor left it out as well as some styling.

If you want the x-axis in steps of 1 hour, which does not quite fit as your sample data barely cover an hour, you can use `scale_x_time(breaks = hms::hms(hours = seq(0, 24, 1)))`. I have chosen half an hour for the breaks.

Another alternative would be to use `scales::breaks_width`, see below.

As the Temperature is missing between 10:15 and 10:22 there is a gap at the right side.

```
df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = WeekDay)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Temperature)) +
  scale_x_time(breaks = hms::hms(hours = seq(0, 24, 0.5)))
  #scale_x_time(breaks = scales::breaks_width("30 min"))
```

[image]